# I wish to insert reply buttons in php-mailer AMENDED

Tags: php

I have created a code which works in the email client as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PLEASE REPLY USING THE BUTTONS</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border:5px;>
<tr>
<td align="center" width="200" height="40" bgcolor="#000091" style="-webkit-    border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;" >
<a href="mailto:xxx@xxx.com?subject=ATTENDING" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">ATTENDING</span></a>
</td>
<td height="10"></td>
<td align="center" width="200" height="40" bgcolor="#000091" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
<a href="mailto:xxx@xxx.com?subject=DINING" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">ATTENDING AND DINING</span></a>
</td>
<td height="10"></td>
<td align="center" width="200" height="40" bgcolor="#000091" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
<a href="mailto:xxx@xxx.com?subject=APOLOGIES" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">APOLOGIES</span></a>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now amended to include html, header, body. It works in a web page and works in an email client.

But placing this into the body text in php-mailer ignores it completely.

How can I ensure that these buttons appear in the mailed text.

I do not understand the response with Yii:: as the page simply jams up.
Is there any easier way to get the html into the page?

Thanks for your assistance

CRG

Answer (score 0):

use setHtmlBody in your code

```
 public function sendEmail($email)
{
    return Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setFrom([$this->email => $this->name])
        ->setSubject('text')
        ->setHtmlBody($this->body)
        ->send();
}
```

Comment: What is Yii:: please

Answer (score 0):

Email html differs greatly from normal html, for various reasons, security being one of them. Many email clients ignore the mailto link completely, implement it poorly, or show a warning to the user.

It is better to avoid it. You could use a form inside you email, or on your website, to allow users to send you a message.

Ref: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2013/06/tip-avoid-using-mailto-links-in-html-email/